# pulseaudio no card detected (needs GUI login)

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa

I have a problem related to pluseaudio on Ubuntu 20.04 Desktop.
I can't get audio working until I log into GUI (gdm) and to set the audio device and profile. pluseaudio can't detect the sound card until I login into GUI Desktop (gdm).

Before GUI login:

> ~$ pacmd list-cards 0 card(s) available.

The moment I login in GUI (gdm), pulseaudio starts automatically and detects cards.

> ~$ pacmd list-cards 1 card(s) available.
> index: 0  name: <alsa_card.pci-0000_02_03.0>  driver: <module-alsa-card.c>

I tried to restart pulseaudio and reload alsa with the command "pulseaudio -k && sudo alsa force-reload" but it also didn't work, because this is a remote system so I don't want to have to go to the office and log in to the GUI every time I restart this PC. Any help is very helpful.
Thank you for your reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by adding user to groups audio and everything works normally.

```
sudo adduser user audio
```

Hope it helps someone having the same problem.